# How does set a variable in one class method to be equal to the value of an instance variable of another class?

Tags: ruby

I want to use the value of an instance variable to set the value of an instance variable in another class.

i.e

If class foo has a variable move

I create two instances of foo each with a different value ( could be the same value)

I have a class bar I want it's initialize method to have a parameters x and y parameter x will be an integer number. parameter y will be the instance name for an instance of foo.

The initialize method for class bar will set the local variable move to the move value of the instance passed in the initialize parameters.

An example taken from one of the answers provided

```
class Bar
  def initialize(x, y)

    @move = y.getmove
    end
  attr_reader :move
end

class foo 
  def initialize (move)
    @move = move
  end

  def getmove
    @move
  end

car = foo.new(3)
train = foo.new(6)

audi = Bar.new(2, car) # instance audi should now have a move variable set to 3
thomas = bar.new(6, train) # instance thomas should now have a move variable set to 6
```

please note I don't want to achieve this through inheritance, as class bar needs to inherit from a different class.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you provide code that illustrates what you want to achieve? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Which part do you find confusing? Class definitions? Field declarations? Assignments? Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: You have a missing `end` before `car = foo.new(3)`, and `foo` should be called `Foo`, and `bar` should be `Bar`, but that aside, everything works... No?

Comment: In class `Bar`, why does `initialize` have parameter `x`?  You don't seem to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you describe:

```
class Bar
  def initialize(x, y)
    @move = y.move
  end
  attr_reader :move
end

Bar.new(2, foo)
```